# use answer .then () outside and use in another part of the code in node js

Tags: node.js, promise, adonis.js

How can I use the answer of a promise outside of. Then what should I do?

```
   arreglo.forEach((item) => {
        if (item.tipoCampo == 3) {
            self.campoSelects(item.tablaCampo)
                .then(resp => {
                    console.log(resp)
                })
                .catch(e => console.log(e))
        }
    });
```

console.log (resp) inside the .then () knows it and prints correctly, but when I want to know resp out of the forEach to use below, it says undefined
Thanks.

Comment: You can't use the response realiably outside of the `forEach` because Promises are asynchronous. You could use a for ... of loop and an async function ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function ). Note that this will make the main function return a Promise.

Comment: a quick and dirty way would be to assign `resp` to `item`, e.g. `item.campoSelectsResult = resp`, this works because inside the then() scope it has access to both item and resp.

Comment: Don't use `forEach`, use `map` at best to generate an array of promises to use with `Promise.all`.

Answer (score 0):

```
arreglo.forEach((item) => {
   if (item.tipoCampo == 3) {
     self.campoSelects(item.tablaCampo)
        .then(resp => {
            logMyData(resp);
        })
         .catch(e => console.log(e))
    }
});

logMyData=(x)=>{
 console.log(x);
}
```

This is just as simple as adding a helper function which executes inside your `.then`

Answer (score 0):

Guessing that you want to be able to access the value within the forloop. Since self.campoSelects is a promise we can use async await.

```
// Call campo selects
function getCampoSelects(_self, tablaCampo) {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    let campoData;

    try {
      campoData = await _self.campoSelects(tablaCampo);
    } catch (err) {
      reject(err);
    }

    resolve(campoData);
  });
}

function happyLittleFunc() {
  const arreglo = [];

  arreglo.forEach(async (item) => {
    if (item.tipoCampo === 3) {
      let campoSelect;

      // Unsure if you are setting self somewhere but it can be passed in here.
      try {
        campoSelect = await getCampoSelects(self, item.tipoCampo);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
      }

      console.log(campoSelect);
    }
  });
}

happyLittleFunc();
```